Flutter on macOS: how to implement "Reveal in Finder" for a document?
Flutter desktop macOS app that works with files.
How to implement a standard "Reveal in Finder" call to open Finder window with folder containing the file and the file selected?
And maybe how to make it cross-platform to have "show in Explorer" when running on Windows?

I do not know most idiomatic way to achieve this in dart/flutter, but I played a little with running different shell commands from Flutter app, and from this point of view, easiest way is to just call open -R /path/to/file (on macOS).
This is code sample for this approach:
// This package is for running shell commands
// flutter pub add process_run
import 'package:process_run/shell.dart';

Future<void> revealFile(String filePath) async {
  final shell = Shell();
  if (Platform.isMacOS) {
    try {
      await shell.run('''
        open -R $filePath
      ''');
    } catch (e) {
      throw 'Could not reveal file: $e';
    }
  // Add branches of code for another platforms here.
  } else {
    throw 'Unsupported platform';
  }
}

I'm no Windows guy myself and I do not know command for this there, but if you have it (I bet there's should be an analogue), you will add another if and start shell with this command and it should work too.

Yes, can always spawn open, I was hoping for something like system API. And AppleScript is being discontinued, so I guess open is the answer.
